# Repeat a php code - how to?

Tags: php

I want this code to repeat for the given id ( if it doesn't find for id shown in example so it will go for 1232 (+1) and so on untill it finds a good id that has the preg_matsh "flv_url" and stops showing me the id that worked)

```
<?php
$id=1231;
$text = file_get_contents("http://www.exemple.com/video". $id ."");
if (preg_match('~flv_url=(.*?)&amp;~si', $text, $body)){
$decoded_url = rawurldecode($body[1]);
echo $decoded_url;
}
else {}
?>
```

Comment: You can change the `if` to `while` (and then remove the `else` block), but you'll likely hit the memory limit if there are too many IDs to be queried.

Comment: Looks like you're crawling a site.. possibly youtube? https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms 4.H. disallows bots from scraping their content.

Comment: I suggest using `curl` instead of `file_get_contents()`, it has error handling.

Comment: Perhaps using an HTML parser would be a better approach, I recommend: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$id=1231;
$match = false;
do {
  $text = file_get_contents("http://www.exemple.com/video". $id++ ."");
  if (preg_match('~flv_url=(.*?)&amp;~si', $text, $body)){
    $match = true;
    $decoded_url = rawurldecode($body[1]);
    echo $decoded_url;
  }
} while(!$match);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `while()` or `for()` or `do()` for repeat your code.code will repeat according to your conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can use for();

```
<?php
for($id=1231;$id!=-1;$id++){
$text = file_get_contents("http://www.exemple.com/video". $id ."");
if (preg_match('~flv_url=(.*?)&amp;~si', $text, $body)){
$decoded_url = rawurldecode($body[1]);
echo $decoded_url;
$id = -1;
}
else {}
}
?>
```