# php, how to iterate through numbers and add as we go along and calculate new numbers

Tags: php, math

I wrote a simple code to calculate a math equation, but I would like to iterate through numbers from `$start` to `$end`. I am making a game, and this page will calculate the amount of experience it takes to reach the next level and insert it into the database. What would be the best way to iterate from `$start` to `$end` and calculate the amount of exp needed for that level?

Code:

```
<?php 

    $start = 1;
    $end = 100;

    $level = $start++;
    $l = $level - 1;
    $exp = ((40*($l * $l)) + (360 * $l)); 

?>
```

As it sits right now it calculates the first level but i cannot for the life of me figure out how to make it go through til it reaches `$end`.

Comment: [for() loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Comment: or `while` loop, `foreach range`, pretty much any loop.

Comment: @MarkBaker wanna put that as an answer and ill accept it. Thank you so much, i was having a brain fart and totally forgot about for() loops lol.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeat a php code - how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695226/repeat-a-php-code-how-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$exp = 0;
for($level = $start; $level <= $end; $level++){
    $exp += 40 * $l ** 2 + 360 * $l;
}
```

Actually, we can use mathematics to make this faster by generalizing the experience level required. Since your experience function is the summation of a quadratic function:

```
  f(n)
= S[1 100] 40n^2 + 360n
= 40n (n + 1) (2n + 1) / 6 + 360n (n + 1) / 2
```

In PHP:

```
40 * $level * ($level + 1) * (2 * $level + 1) / 6 + 360 * $level * ($level + 1) / 2
```

Or simplify it further if you like.

This is definitely faster than calculating a loop 100 times.

If $start is not 1, simply use `f(end) - f(start - 1)`.

Comment: Thank you, this method is definitely much more efficient!!! This page will only be used 1 time to do the calculations then it inserts it into a database.

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the needed xp for every single level, so you should put the calculation code inside a loop that starts at your lowest level and proceeds until it hits the top limit / end level. You can choose from two different loop types in PHP, the for-loop and the while-loop.

Personally, I would choose the while-loop for this specific "problem", but that is a thing everyone has to decide on his own. The code for your calculator would look like this:

```
 // Create an extra variable to store the level for which you are currently calculating the needed xp 
 $i = $start;

 // The while-loop (do this code until the current level hits the max level as specified)
 while($i <= end) {
    // use $i to calculate your exp, its the current level
    // Insert code here...

    // then add 1 to $i and do the same again (repeat the code inside loop)
    $i++;
 }
```

Here are some links to the documentation of php:

[while-loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)
[for-loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Comment: explain how this Fixes the OP's question, that will be more beneficial to everyone

Comment: @davejal did not have much time, added some explanation lines now. hopefully it is easy to understand